# How to get LocalDate(yyyy-MM-dd) format from given OffsetDatetime and return as OffsetDatetime without zone offset?

Tags: java, date, java-time

I currently receive java.time.OffsetDateTime with offset as following:

2021-06-05T18:29:31Z

2021-06-05T18:29:38.723Z

Is it possible to convert this to LocalDate format(yyyy-MM-dd) and **return as java.time.OffsetDateTime**?

I tried the following with DateTimeFormatter but with no luck.

```
        String offsetDateTimeString = offsetDateTime.toString();

        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .toFormatter();
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetDateTimeString, dateTimeFormatter)
```

If converting to yyyy-MM-dd format is not possible, then converting to the format without zone offset is also not possible.

```
        String offsetDateTimeString = offsetDateTime.toString();
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
                .toFormatter();

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetDateTimeString, dateTimeFormatter);
```

I get `DateTimeParseException` when run this code:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-06-05T18:39:51.578Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
```

I need to return the given dates as "yyyy-MM-dd" or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" format in OffsetDateTime.

Comment: When you're neither interested in the time or the offset, then why do you OffsetDateTime as return type and not LocalDate?

Comment: I need to pass the value in java.time.OffsetDateTime only. That was the given requirement.

Comment: Then you're also required to have a time portion and an offset, that's OffsetDateTime requires. You can change the time or the offset, but you can't remove it.

Comment: A `OffsetDateTime` will *always* have a Date, a Time, and an Offset. It's in the name: Offset-Date-Time. It cannot not have one of those 3 parts. If you want a Date without a Time or an Offset, you need to use `LocalDate`, and to have a Date and a Time without an Offset, you need to use `LocalDateTime`. --- You can however create an `OffsetDateTime` when the Time and Offset values are 0. Actually, the `Z` offset is already 0, so you just need to change the time to `0` too.

Comment: *FYI:* When *displaying* the value, you always have the option to apply a custom `DateTimeFormatter` what only displays the Date part: `offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)`

Comment: @ZafrullahSyed I know I didn’t give you the answer you had hoped for. I am curious to hear whether it was still somehow helpful and whether you have any doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have an `OffsetDateTime` without offset nor one without time of day. As the name says, an `OffsetDateTime` necessarily consists of a date, a time of day and an offset from UTC or GMT. What you asked is a bit like asking for a negative number without a minus sign or a `boolean` with the value `t` rather then `true`.

Also an `OffsetDateTime` cannot have a format. You can have any format you like, but not in a date-time object (also not in a `LocalDate`), only in a `String`. What you see when you print your `OffsetDateTime` is the result of calling its `toString` method. The documentation of that method says:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXXXX`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXXXX`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSXXXXX`
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of
> the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

You notice that all of the possible formats include at least hour and minute  and offset.

So what to do instead? Two suggestions one of which may be useable in your situation:

1. Set the `OffsetDateTime` to the start of the day in UTC.
2. Set the `OffsetDateTime` to the start of the day in the default time zone of the JVM.

In code: the start of the day in UTC (always 00:00):

```
    // Example received value
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(
            2021, 6, 5, 18, 29, 38, 723_000_000, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    
    OffsetDateTime dateOnly = offsetDateTime
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(dateOnly);
```

Output:

> 2021-06-05T00:00Z

The start of the day in the default time zone (also typically 00:00):

```
    OffsetDateTime dateOnly = offsetDateTime
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
```

When I ran in Asia/Omsk time zone, the output was:

> 2021-06-06T00:00+06:00

### Link

[Documentation of `OffsetDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString())